# hog features output array returns a very few values

Tags: python, arrays

```
fd, hog_image = feature.hog(grayscale, orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(8, 8), cells_per_block=(2, 2), visualise=True)
print(hog_image.size)
```

This outputs a value  8192 but when I print(hog_image). It gives me an array of very few values. I dont understand these  values. What does this array tell? Why are the values empty.

```
img = imread(contours.jpg)
imshow(img)
print(img.shape)

resized_img = resize(img, (128,64)) 
imshow(resized_img) 
print(resized_img.shape)

grayscale = rgb2gray(resized_img)
imshow(grayscale)

fd, hog_image = feature.hog(grayscale, orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(8, 8), cells_per_block=(2, 2), visualise=True)
#print(hog_image)
print(hog_image.size)
```

> [[0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0. ]
>    [0.         0.         0.04045185 ... 0.02035863 0.         0. ]
>    [0.         0.01418138 0.         ... 0.         0.00873405 0. ]
>    ...
>    [0.         0.00782422 0.         ... 0.         0.00160013 0. ]
>    [0.         0.         0.00335884 ... 0.01116131 0.         0. ]
>    [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0. ]]

This is the array which I am getting. Please tell me the meaning of this array

Comment: Please format your code so it is understood by others.